# Titan: Some key(s) on index verticesIndex do not currently have status REGISTERED

Tags: titan

When creating index, I get this message while waiting for index to be enabled.

I use this line of code

```
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, indexName).status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call();
```

> 53090 [main] INFO  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher  - Some key(s) on index verticesIndex do not currently have status REGISTERED: firstName=ENABLED,lastName=ENABLED,fieldPosition=ENABLED,name=ENABLED,description=ENABLED,pitcher=ENABLED,location=ENABLED,medium=ENABLED,source=ENABLED,type=ENABLED,sport=ENABLED

It keeps printing a lot for all indexes I have. Am I doing anything wrong? How to avoid such message?

Comment: If all of the keys show `ENABLED`, then your index (in this case `verticesIndex`) already exists. Were you trying to create a new index from scratch, or modify and re-index an existing index?

Comment: I'm confused, what are the different states of an index?

Comment: I found it confusing also. There's `INSTALLED` which means it's brand-new. It will automatically transition to `REGISTERED`. Then you must manually enable to get `ENABLED` state. If you want to you can disable an existing index and it will become `DISABLED`. Only indexes in the `ENABLED` state will handle queries.

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0_docs/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/schema/SchemaStatus.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of the keys show `ENABLED`, then your index (in this case `verticesIndex`) already exists, so it doesn't make sense to wait for it to become `REGISTERED`.

To avoid this unnecessary waiting, you may use this code as a guide.

```
if (index.getIndexStatus(pk).equals(SchemaStatus.INSTALLED))
    ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, indexName).status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call();
```

A summary of the possible index states in Titan:

- `INSTALLED` which means the index is brand-new. It will automatically transition to `REGISTERED`.
- `REGISTERED` means all the database nodes are aware of the index, but it's not ready for use.
- `ENABLED` means the index is active. This is the only state where the index will handle queries.
- `DISABLED` - if you want to get rid of an index, you can manually disable it to get to this state.

Ref: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0_docs/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/schema/SchemaStatus.java

Comment: I have just added a code example to demonstrate a way to avoid it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Would you please point me to documentation where it states that I have to manually switch to `ENABLED` state? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Now that I'm looking I may be wrong. I was working recently on re-indexing (http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-admin.html) which has "enabling" as a separate step. I think for a brand-new index it will be automatically enabled.